# Why do scripting changes to the Skybox Material not reset when play mode over?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript, skybox

My Unity app animates the scene's Skybox Material Exposure property over time (based on audio). The Material asset in my project file has Exposure=1 (initial value). This works great.

When I play the app inside Unity:

1. Before play, I select the Material in Project (to see what's
   happening),
2. Play the app in Unity,
3. As soon as app starts, the Material's Exposure is set to a very low
   value (as expected),
4. The Skybox Exposure animates as expected (i.e., Skybox is
   changing to the music),
5. The Exposure value (in Inspector) does **not** change after the first change at start (#3), during the play (seems odd),
6. When I exit play mode, the Exposure (in Inspector) is set to the last
   value during play (which is not displayed in the Inspector while running).

==> I expected the Material to return to its pre-play values after exiting.

**IMPORTANT**: If I try this same experiment with say a Sphere radius (no scripting though), and I manually change the sphere's radius while playing, when I exit play mode it resets (as expected) to its original pre-play value.

Clearly, I am missing something very core to Unity. I've read everything I can find & still lost. (Wondering if the issue is default Hideflags on the scene's skybox or something similar.)

Scene controller script that changes skybox.material.exposure each frame:

```
public class AnimateSkyboxFromAudio : BaseAnimateFromAudio {
    protected override void Start() {
         base.Start ();
    }

    protected override void MyUpdate () {
        float rms = GetAttrByName (AudioAnalyzer.RMS);
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat ("_Exposure", rms * 5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expected the Material to return to its pre-play values after
>   exiting.

`RenderSettings.skybox` works differently than other GameObjects with materials. It returns **shared material reference** unlike a unique material returned by `Renderer.material` when its material property is accessed.

So, you must make a back-up of the material before modifying it. When you click stop, assign the backup material back to `RenderSettings.skybox`. Both of these can be done in the `Start()` and the `OnDisable()` function. You make a backup material by calling the Material class constructor with the Material parameter.(`Material newMat = new Material(RenderSettings.skybox)`).

If you **only** are changing the `_Exposure` property then you don't even need to make the material backup. Just backup the `_Exposure` property with `RenderSettings.skybox.GetFloat("_Exposure");` then re-assign it when stop is clicked.

> The Exposure value (in Inspector) does not change after the first
>   change at start (#3), during the play (seems odd),

Call `DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();` after you change the material values.

Example of changing the Skybox `_Exposure` property with a UI `Slider`:

```
public Slider slider;
Material backUpMaterial;

void Start()
{
    slider.minValue = 0f;
    slider.maxValue = 3f;
    slider.value = 1.3f;


    //Get Material Backup
    backUpMaterial = makeSkyboxBackUp();

    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { sliderCallBack(slider.value); });
}

void sliderCallBack(float value)
{
    RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Exposure", value);
    DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();
}

Material makeSkyboxBackUp()
{
    return new Material(RenderSettings.skybox);
}


//Restore skybox material back to the Default values
void OnDisable()
{
    RenderSettings.skybox = backUpMaterial;
    DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();
    slider.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(delegate { sliderCallBack(slider.value); });
}
```

Since you have already modified the original copy of the `skybox` settings, I suggest you reset it by setting the `_Exposure` property to `1.3` which is the default value, then try the solution above.

Comment: Thanks! How on earth did you know that skybox.material was a shared reference?  I've read everything on Unity and did not see that anywhere.

Comment: I don't think you read the document. For the second question I  answered, it says **"If you change the skybox in playmode, you have to use the `DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment` function call to update the ambient probe."** in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings-skybox.html).

Comment: For you first question and your comment, Unity failed to mention this in `RenderSettings.skybox` [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings-skybox.html) ,instead they mentioned it in `Skybox.material`[documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Skybox-material.html) which says **"The material used by the skybox.
Note that unlike `Renderer.material`, this returns a shared material reference and not a unique duplicate."**.

Comment: That is their mistake, not yours. I think they expect you to know that `RenderSettings.skybox` and `Skybox.material` returns the-same material the `Skybox` is using.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to answer and provide code example.